# ¿Cómo instalo un nuevo paquete en swi prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

Estoy tratando de agregar la funcionalidad de validar expresiones regulares a una prueba unitaria y para ello me hice el siguiente código:

```
:-['C:/Users/miusuario/Documents/Prolog/html_dynamic_string.pl'].
:- begin_tests(expression_matter).
:- use_module(library(regex)).

test(example_test) :-
        generate_color(Color)
        ,atom_chars(Color,[H|_])
        ,assertion(H == '#').

test(example_test) :-
        generate_color(Color)
        ,atom_chars(Color,L)
        ,length(L,N)
        ,assertion(N == 7).

test(example_test) :-
        generate_color(Color)
        ,Color =~ '#[A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9][A-Fa-f0-9]'/i
        .

:- end_tests(expression_matter).
```

Esto basado en el código que hallé en la página de swi-prolog [del paquete](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/list?p=regex) que es algo así:

```
:- use_module(library(regex)).
?- '99 Bottles of Beer' =~ '[0-9]+ bottles'/i.
true.
```

El problema es que me da el error:

> ERROR:    source_sink `regex' does not exist

> Warning: c:/users/miusuario//documents/prolog/html_dynamic_string_asserts.pl:4:

> Warning:    Goal (directive) failed: plunit_expression_matter:use_module(regex)

> ERROR: c:/users/miusuario//documents/prolog/html_dynamic_string_asserts.pl:19:14: Syntax error: Operator expected

He ido al [repositorio del paquete](https://github.com/mndrix/regex/releases) y me he descargado el zip para la versión `v0.3.3`.
¿Y ahora cómo lo instalo?

Answer (score 1):

primeramente busqué el paquete usando el comando desde la consola interactiva

```
pack_list('regex').
```

> % Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok

> p regex@0.3.3               - Regular expressions

> true.

Luego usé le comando para instalarlo sin dar opciones extra:

```
pack_install('regex').
```

% Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
Install regex@0.3.3 from http://github.com/mndrix/regex/archive/v0.3.3.zip Y/n?

Create directory for packages
(1) * c:/users/miusuario/appdata/local/swi-prolog/pack
(2)   c:/programdata/swi-prolog/pack
(3)   Cancel

Your choice?
% Contacting server at https://www.swi-prolog.org/pack/query ... ok
% "v0.3.3.zip" was downloaded 882 times
Package:                regex
Title:                  Regular expressions
Installed version:      0.3.3
Author:                 Michael Hendricks michael@ndrix.org
Maintainer:             Michael Hendricks michael@ndrix.org
Packager:               Michael Hendricks michael@ndrix.org
Home page:              https://github.com/mndrix/regex
Download URL:           https://github.com/mndrix/regex/archive/v0.3.3.zip
Install "regex-0.3.3.zip" (12,180 bytes) Y/n?
true

Todo lo he documentado [en mi sitio](https://javapro.org/programming-languages/como-instalar-un-nuevo-paquete-en-swi-prolog/) en caso de que queiras un poco más de info.